# strstr($categoryname, ' ', true) <-- the TRUE bit not working

Tags: php, strstr

I'm trying to split up a string where there's a space, which should be easy enough,

```
strstr($categoryname, ' ', true)
```

in my localhost works fine but online it doesn't. If I remove the TRUE it returns the portion of the string after the space, but with true there, it returns nothing,

what am I doing wrong, it there a better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) or [strtok](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtok.php) function

Answer (score 2):

Check your PHP version. The *before_needle* parameter was added in 5.3.0. If you need to get anything that comes before the first space, there are many other ways to do so. One such way would be to use the `explode` function and grab the first item in the resulting array:

```
$categoryname = "This is the name";
$results = explode(" ", $categoryname);
echo $results[0];
```

Comment: bugger, how else can I get to the first part of that category name then? Sorry for being stupid, I'm a learner :)

Comment: Thanks jonathan, very kind to help me out